# RC Servo motor power supply

Tags: servo

In my RC servo motor datasheet the shall current is 600 mA. My Arduino cannot supply that much of current so, I decided to use an DC adapter to supply the power and arduino to control the Servo. My question is - Can I connect a DC adapter of 5 volts and 1A to the servo. I have read some where that servo motor just take current (not voltage) what it needs even tough you supply more than enough. Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the motor will only take the current it requires (and that current will vary depending on load - perhaps more than 600 mA when starting, and much less when running with a very light load.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 5V 1A should be more than adequate for that servo.

Based on my own playing with with a Tower Hobbies Royal Titan, years ago, I suggest putting about a 250 uF capacitor across the servo supply, ideally as electrically close to the servo as you can.  A servo can pull surprising current spikes.